# unable to run NameNode and DataNode in Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

With the command "start-dfs.sh", I am not able to start NameNode

Here is the terminal outputs:

```
ubuntu@UBUNTU:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ cat hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-UBUNTU.log
2014-10-20 21:01:22,678 INFO   
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = UBUNTU/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.3.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.3.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.3.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.3.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.3.0.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1567123; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-02-11T13:40Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65
************************************************************/
2014-10-20 21:01:22,875 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2014-10-20 21:01:30,764 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-10-20 21:01:36,396 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode : 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode’: Operation not permitted

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:1819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:1861)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1973)
2014-10-20 21:01:36,456 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/" 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:1870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1973)
2014-10-20 21:01:36,469 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2014-10-20 21:01:36,521 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at UBUNTU/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
ubuntu@UBUNTU:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$
```

Comment: is there a directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/ ? Check the line starting with 2014-10-20 21:01:36,456 FATAL

Comment: yes there is a directory which I made at the time of installation. I followed the steps from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Try to change permission for the directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode like "chmod 755 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode" from terminal.

Comment: Just mention which tutorial you are following? did you formatted the namenode at initial?

Comment: What all have u tried? Tried formatting namenode, stopping all instances, which all deamons are running currently ?